# Mysql vrachar field check on zero fail

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i have a varchar field status with values like 'New','close' etc

When i try a sql `select * from table where status=0`

its returning results which have status . Its not returning status null .

Its not returning any result on status =1 .

Any idea why this `0` check fail on varchar?  `status='0'` works correctly

Answer (score -1):

if I understand you correctly you want to get all rows with status=Null so you should do:

```
SELECT * FROM table where status is Null;
```

You can check it here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/ for example on table orders with:

```
SELECT * FROM orders where comments is Null;
```

or if you want the oposite you should use

```
SELECT * FROM orders where comments is not Null;
```

in general you shouldn't compare varchar fields with numbers (like 0 or 1)

EDIT:

Why do you think it's wrong? It's just different than you think, please see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html - mysql tries very hard to convert and compare what you gave in the query.

So from your example, if you had some row with status='1', your query would result in that row, as quote from that link says:

> there are many different strings that may convert to the value 1, such as '1', ' 1', or '1a').

Comment: I was just asking why mysql return result when sql is wrong !!